# Prove $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}}{\log|x|}$ (without using L'Hopital)

Tags: calculus, limits

In Tom Apostol's book the L'Hopital's rule was given only for $\frac{0}{0}$ case, so I would like to use a different way to solve: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}}{\log|x|}$.

One idea I had was this:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = 0 \iff (\forall \epsilon>0. \exists \delta > 0 \mid 0 < |x| < \delta \implies |\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}| < \epsilon)$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \log|x| = -\infty \iff ( \forall N > 0.\exists \delta > 0 \mid 0 < |x|<\delta \implies |\log|x|| > N > 0 \implies 0 < \frac{1}{|\log|x||} < \frac{1}{N}) $

Then we have:

$\forall \epsilon>0. N > \frac{1}{\epsilon} > 1. \exists \delta > 0 \mid 0 < |x|<\delta \implies 0 < \frac{1}{|\log|x||} < \frac{1}{N} < 1 \land |\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}| < \epsilon \implies |\frac{\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}}{\log|x|}| < \epsilon$

That implies $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}}{\log|x|} = 0$, by definition.

Is that correct? Is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're right, but two $\delta$'s you took may be different, so you must set $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ for above two statements. Then, you can take $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ and proceed.

Comment: The first two lines use different deltas, even though they share the same name, but the last line, where the first two are combined, have only one delta. Are you referring to the first two lines, that I should use $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ there, and only later combine them into one (e.g. as $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$)?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Since the limit statements only ensures the 'existence' of such positive numbers $\delta$. So you cannot say that they are equal. That's why you need such modification in proof.

Answer (score 0):

REMARK.-$\dfrac{\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}}{\log|x|}$ is not an undeterminated form when $x\rightarrow  0$. In fact the numerator tends to $0$ and the denominator tends to $-\infty$ so the limit is clearly equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but I would like to be able to prove the clear part.

Comment: Why then mention   L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: https://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/12/25/compute-the-limit-of-the-given-function-7/

Comment: Okay, dear friend. Greetings